# Is there a Python data structure that uses (key, key) pairs instead of (key, value) pairs?

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to keep track of a relationship between a number and a string. I want each item in the pair to act as a key that points to the other value, such that I could get the string provided the number or the number provided the string, and I want them to be linked such that if either the number or the string changes they still correctly point to the corresponding element.

My first attempt was to use a simple list:

```py
ids = [
    "id1", # 0
    "id2", # 1
    "id3"  # 2
]
# getting id from number is trivial
string = ids[1]
# getting the number is also pretty easy
number = ids.index("id2")
```

The problem with this implementation is that the numeric keys are not guaranteed to be contiguous; meaning the list would have to be impractically large over wide numeric ranges, and unused values would have to be set to `None` or similar, plus the performance penalty of linearly searching through a huge list of mostly nothing.

Given these limitations, a pair of dictionaries seems more applicable:

```py
number_to_string = { 1: "A" }
string_to_number = { "A": 1 }
```

However, I want the two values to be dynamically linked, so if one pair changes the other is reflected as well. With this method any time I make a change with one I have to manually change it in the other:

```py
# change (1, "A") to (1, "B")
number = 1
new_id = "B"

old_id = number_to_string[number]
number_to_string[number] = "B"
del string_to_number[old_id]
string_to_number[new_id] = number

print(number_to_string[1]) # "B"
```

It would also be nice to combine the two dictionaries as one, since they are conceptually linked together. The syntax I want would probably look more like:

```py
link_structure = ... # something
link_structure.set_pair(1, "A")
link_structure.get_linked(1) # "A"
link_structure.get_linked("A") # 1
link_structure.set_pair(1, "B")
# and so on
```

Basically I want the advantages of dictionary representation but across two keys that are linked to each other instead of a value. Does Python have anything out-of-the-box to achieve this more elegantly, or should I just use the double dict method and roll my own class?